# Best library to parse HTML with Python 3 and example?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to Python completely and am using Python 3.1 on Windows (pywin). I need to parse some HTML, to essentially extra values between specific HTML tags and am confused at my array of options, and everything I find is suited for Python 2.x. I've read raves about Beautiful Soup, HTML5Lib and lxml, but I cannot figure out how to install any of these on Windows.

Questions:

1. What HTML parser do you recommend?
2. How do I install it? (Be gentle, I'm completely new to Python and remember I'm on Windows)
3. Do you have a simple example on how to use the recommended library to snag HTML from a specific URL and return the value out of say something like this:

   <div class="foo"><table><tr><td>foo</td></tr></table><a class="link" href='/blahblah'>Link</a></div>

(say we want to return "/blahblah")

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Web-scraping in Python 3 is currently very poorly supported; all the decent libraries work only with Python 2. If you *must* web scrape in Python, use Python 2.

Although [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is oft recommended (every question regarding web scraping with Python in Stack Overflow suggests it), it's not as good for Python 3 as it is for Python 2; I couldn't even install it as the installation code was still Python 2.

As for adequate and simple-to-install solutions for Python 3, you can try [the library's HTML parser](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/html.parser.html), although quite barebones, it comes with Python 3.

Comment: Any idea how to use the built in HTML parser to get at the content of the tags?

Comment: Beautiful Soup has a good write up on it's current status. 

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/3.1-problems.html

Answer (score 7):

If your HTML is well formed, you have many options, such as `sax` and `dom`.  If it is not well formed you need a fault tolerant parser such as `Beautiful soup`, [element tidy](http://effbot.org/zone/element-tidylib.htm), or [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/lxmlhtml.html)'s HTML parser. No parser is perfect, when presented with a variety of broken HTML, sometimes I have to try more then one.  `Lxml` and `Elementree` use a mostly compatible api that is more of a standard than `Beautiful soup`.

In my opinion, `lxml` is the best module for working with xml documents, but the `ElementTree` included with python is still pretty good.  In the past I have used `Beautiful soup` to convert HTML to xml and construct `ElementTree` for processing the data.

Answer (score 5):

[**BeautifulSoup**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), with its version 3.1.0.1 (January 2009) also work with Python 3.x.

I do not have have direct experience with BeautifulSoup under Py3k (although this soon should change...).   I just read, however, that [Version 3.1.0 of Beautiful Soup does significantly worse on real-world HTML than its previous versions](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/3.1-problems.html), so I may try and wait if possible (i.e. stay with Python 2.6 a bit longer).

Answer (score 5):

I'm currently using [lxml](http://lxml.de/), and on Windows I used the installation binary from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml.

```
import lxml.html
page = lxml.html.fromstring(...)
title = page.xpath('//head/title/text()')[0]
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is way late, but for future reference, Beautiful Soup 4.3.2 is available as of Oct. 2013.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/

It is compatible with Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

you might try [beautifulsoup4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) which is compatible with both python2 and python3 you can use it easily by

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup("<p>Some<b>bad<i>HTML")
```

Answer (score -1):

Beautiful Soup4 supports python3 and it could parse html content easily. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ contains several examples and they are useful.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30523808)