# How do I extract data from HTML page using Python3.1?

Tags: html, python-3.x, information-extraction

I have about 1000 pages locally stored on the disk containing something similar to the below example.

```
<html>
<body>
<li>User Dave<sup><a href="" title="" onClick="" class="">?</a></sup></li>
<li>UserID<sup><a href="" title="" onClick="" class="">?</a></sup>: 00000001</li>
</body>
</html>
```

I need help figuring out how to extract string Dave fromt the 3rd line and to load it up into UserName list.
Also, I need to extract 00000001 from the fourth line and load it up in UserID list.

Please help, thanks...

Comment: [lxml](http://lxml.de) is nice too.

Comment: I removed the tag "data mining". There is no advanced statistical analysis happening here, only "information extraction".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best library to parse HTML with Python 3 and example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505041/best-library-to-parse-html-with-python-3-and-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the html.parser module (http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/html.parser.html#module-html.parser).

Answer (score 0):

You can parse XHTML/XML using MiniDom:

- http://wiki.python.org/moin/MiniDom
- http://developer.yahoo.com/python/python-xml.html

Alternatively, Python has a built in HTMLParser:

- http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html