# xml.etree.ElementTree fails to read <img ...>

Tags: html, xml, python-3.x

I want to parse a html snippet like below with the xml.etree.ElementTree
module of python 3.

```html
<html>
  <table>
    ...
    <td><img src="myimg.png" title="mytitle" alt="myalttext"></td>
    ...
  </table>
</html>
```

But there is a **"mismatched tag"** parsing error due to the img-tag, which is closed with **">"** not with **"/>"**. No error occurs when I close the tag with **"/>"**.

However, I'm loading that html from a website, so I just can't expect them to
close the img-tag with "/>" (additionally this seems also to be a common way
to just close it simply with ">", see [W3Schools on images](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp))

Do you have an idea how I can avoid this? I would also like to avoid to parse it manually before passing it to the xml.etree.ElementTree parser. I would also like to avoid using other parsers, unless they are already available
in the default python library.

Comment: The HTML snippet is not well-formed XML (because of the image element not being closed properly). Therefore you cannot parse it with ElementTree, which is for XML only.

Comment: There must be a way to just ignore that img-tag. I don't even need that piece of information in the img tag. Of course I could remove it via regex before passing it to the parser or close the tag to achieve a well-formed XML. But there is no other way?

Comment: ElementTree works with XML, not "almost XML", and it is not possible to just ignore the `img` tag. But there are many other options. I would recommend you to try BeautifulSoup (even though it's not in the standard library): https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/11709079/407651 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/2505041/407651.

Comment: Not what I wanted originally, but finally, I parsed it by myself and did some replacements before pass it to the xml.etree.ElementTree parser. Not the most generic and future-orientated, but quick and it works fine. There also was other stuff to do like defining unknown entities in the CDATA section and introduction of a root element. @mzjn: Thanks anyway, I had a look on BeautifulSoup and I will give it a try in one of the upcoming projects.

Comment: Better going with BeautifulSoup from the beginning. Would have saved me a lot of time, since also encountered further troubles. So I just switched to BeautifulSoup and it just works from the scratch. Had to learn it the hard way.